# VS 2010 SQL Update for SQL Statement

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

Please bear with me as I'm just beginning to learn this stuff.

I have a VS 2010 Web project up and I'm trying to understand how I can make a custom `UpdateCommand` (Because I chose to write my own SQL statement, I do not have the option for VS 2010 to auto generate an update command for me.) Problem is: I don't know what the `UpdateCommand` should look like. Here is my Select:

```
SELECT * FROM Dbo.MainAsset, dbo.Model, dbo.Hardware WHERE MainAsset.device = Hardware.DeviceID AND MainAsset.model = Model.DeviceID
```

Which, VS 2010 turns into:

```
SELECT MainAsset.pk, MainAsset.img, MainAsset.device, MainAsset.model, MainAsset.os, MainAsset.asset, MainAsset.serial, MainAsset.inyear, MainAsset.expyear, MainAsset.site, MainAsset.room, MainAsset.teacher, MainAsset.FirstName, MainAsset.LastName, MainAsset.Notes, MainAsset.Dept, MainAsset.AccountingCode, Model.Model AS Hardware, Model.pk AS Model, Model.DeviceID, Hardware.Computer, Hardware.pk AS Expr3, Hardware.DeviceID AS Expr4 FROM MainAsset INNER JOIN Hardware ON MainAsset.device = Hardware.DeviceID INNER JOIN Model ON MainAsset.model = Model.DeviceID
```

How would I approach updating one column, say "MainAsset.site" if that's changed in the Gridview DDL? Any help constructive help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are missing something from your question. Are you just asking for the syntax of an update command using joins, or are you asking how to create an `UpdateCommand` override for some data access API like Entity Framework?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I understand the UpdateCommand part in the <asp:SqlDataSource> tags. I'm asking for how the syntax should look for the UpdateCommand. I've tried a few things, but I don't understand how to "connect the dots", I guess :/

Answer (score 2):

I am asuming that you would like to use the UpdateCommand with a SqlDataSource and a GridView.

The update command [uses SQL](http://www.sqlcourse.com/update.html):

```
Update yourTable SET columnName = 'yourValue';
Update MainAsset Set site ='http://stackoverflow.com';
```

In the [example from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand.aspx) the database columns (fields) are bound to the gridview1. The values for the BoundField can be passed by using the value of DataField with an @. The database coulmn LastName will be bound to a grid column `<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" />` and in the update command @LastName is used to pass the value:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceMode="DataSet"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Title FROM Employees"
      UpdateCommand="Update Employees SET   
         FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,
         Title=@Title WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID"
      OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>

  <asp:GridView
      id="GridView1"
      runat="server"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      DataKeyNames="EmployeeID"
      AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
      <columns>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title" />
      </columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

### Update to address your comment

Your `Select * from Dbo.MainAsset, dbo.Model ...` loads data from different tables and displays them as one big table. This is called a join. Your Select uses the [old join syntax instead of the newer syntax](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/old-join-syntax-vs-new)

I am uncertain if i understand your comment:  "I'm asking for how the syntax should look for the UpdateCommand." In your update do you want to update the values in all 3 tables (MainAsset, Model and Hardware)?
If this is the case we need to know the single columns that are displayed in your grid. You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql) or at this [update join explanation](http://www.katieandemil.com/sql-update-statement-syntax-join-examples-using-sql-server#sqlupdatejoin) to better understand updates with a join.

#### Update 2 Syntax for UpdateCommand

1. How I can make a custom UpdateCommand?
2. How would I approach updating one column, say "MainAsset.site"
3. How to update a record if a dropdownlist changes?

First you need to know how a [normal update statement in SQL Server](http://www.katieandemil.com/sql-update-statement-syntax-join-examples-using-sql-server#sqlupdatejoin) looks like:

```
UPDATE MainAsset
    SET site= NewValueForSite
        ,teacher = 'Dr. Seuss'
    WHERE rowId = FilterValue
```

To create a custom update command you write the sql that you need and assign / pass it to the property [UpdateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand.aspx) of SqlDataSource.
You could do the following (assuming that pk stands for primary key and identifies a row):

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      // ... see above          
      UpdateCommand="Update MainAsset SET   
         site=@site
         ,teacher=@teacher,
         WHERE pk=@pk"
      OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Regarding your third question i would like to point you at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141277/asp-net-dropdownlist-populates-gridview):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSite" runat="server"  
   AutoPostBack="True" 
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionHasChanged"
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="site"
   DataValueField="pk" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

Comment: Hey there, three. Thanks for your information. I'm going to give the suggestions a shot. What I meant in your question back to me was, in VS 2010, when you manually enter your own SQL Update command, what would it need to look like with the information I gave? I think you gave me enough information to look at though, so I'll give that a shot and see what I end up with. If I am able to figure it out, I'll post my results, in case someone else comes across a similar situation. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Long story short, here is what I did:

The DDL in question:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="site" SortExpression="site">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSites" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        DataSourceID="RetrieveSiteSQL" DataTextField="Sites" DataValueField="Sites" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("site") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
```

I figured out that my RetrieveSiteSQL was not the one that needed the update command, Instead, it was my "main" SQL Data Source that was updated when I click on "Update" (in the edit template.) So, I figured out that the UpdateCommand="UPDATE MainAsset ..." statement had to look something similar to:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE MainAsset SET [site] = @Site WHERE [pk] = @pk">
```

I have a different problem now, but it's a separate issue, so I will post a different question on this site.

Thanks for your help all.